# JavaScript - Group array of objects into sub-arrays based on multiple properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

I need to solve the following problem with a function that takes an array of objects as an argument and solves all three cases.
Given an array of objects, how do I group them into sub-arrays based on several conditions? I am looking for errors in the payment system and want to receive an array of duplicated transactions (sorted by transaction time ascending).

Transactions are considered duplicates when: manufacturer, amount, category are exactly the same AND time between transactions is less than 45 seconds.

I am looking for an ES6 solution and I am sure that it would include .reduce method.

I tried working on it, by following reduce gives me an object based on manufacturer key, and this is not a result I would like to achieve as I need sub-arrays instead of objects and need more conditions than just a manufacturer.

```js
let groupedArr = data.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => {
 accumulator[currentValue.manufacturer] = [...accumulator[currentValue.manufacturer] || [], currentValue];
 return accumulator;
}, {});
```

#### Case 1:

INPUT:

```js
const data = [{
    id: 3,
    manufacturer: 'audi',
    amount: 40,
    category: 'leasing',
    transaction: '2020-03-02T10:34:30.000Z'
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    manufacturer: 'audi',
    amount: 40,
    category: 'leasing',
    transaction: '2020-03-02T10:34:38.000Z'
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    manufacturer: 'mercedes',
    amount: 20,
    category: 'leasing',
    transaction: '2020-03-05T12:00:00.000Z'
  },
  {
    id: 7,
    manufacturer: 'audi',
    amount: 40,
    category: 'leasing',
    transaction: '2020-03-20T11:00:00.000Z'
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    manufacturer: 'mercedes',
    amount: 20,
    category: 'leasing',
    transaction: '2020-03-05T12:00:44.000Z'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    manufacturer: 'volkswagen',
    amount: 2,
    category: 'credit',
    transaction: '2020-03-05T12:00:45.000Z'
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    manufacturer: 'audi',
    amount: 40,
    category: 'leasing',
    transaction: '2020-03-02T10:35:17.000Z'
  },
]
```

Expected output:

```js
[[{
    id: 3,
    manufacturer: 'audi',
    amount: 40,
    category: 'leasing',
    transaction: '2020-03-02T10:34:30.000Z'
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    manufacturer: 'audi',
    amount: 40,
    category: 'leasing',
    transaction: '2020-03-02T10:34:38.000Z'
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    manufacturer: 'audi',
    amount: 40,
    category: 'leasing',
    transaction: '2020-03-02T10:35:17.000Z'
  }],
  [{
    id: 1,
    manufacturer: 'mercedes',
    amount: 20,
    category: 'leasing',
    transaction: '2020-03-05T12:00:00.000Z'
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    manufacturer: 'mercedes',
    amount: 20,
    category: 'leasing',
    transaction: '2020-03-05T12:00:44.000Z'
  }]
]
```

#### Case 2:

INPUT:

```js
const data = [{
    id: 2,
    manufacturer: 'audi',
    amount: 40,
    category: 'leasing',
    transaction: '2020-03-02T10:34:30.000Z'
  },
  {
    id: 7,
    manufacturer: 'audi',
    amount: 40,
    category: 'leasing',
    transaction: '2020-03-20T11:00:00.000Z'
  }]
```

Expected output:

```js
[]
```

Explanation: More than 45 seconds between transactions should output an empty array.

#### Case 3:

INPUT:

```js
const data = [{
    id: 2,
    manufacturer: 'audi',
    amount: 40,
    category: 'leasing',
    transaction: '2020-03-02T10:34:30.000Z'
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    manufacturer: 'audi',
    amount: 40,
    category: 'credit',
    transaction: '2020-03-02T10:34:40.000Z'
  }]
```

Expected output:

```js
[]
```

Explanation: Less than 45 seconds, but category is different so it's not considered a duplicate.

Comment: _"need more conditions than just a manufacturer"_ - Then don't only use the manufacturer key as the property name. _"I need sub-arrays instead of objects"_ - Just convert it after you've grouped the entries.

Comment: Why would id=2 (volkswagen, credit) not be included in output for case 1? See my answer for case 1, I don't understand why you want to exclude that. Also, when there is a duplicate (within 40 seconds, which one is kept - the one which was "earlier" in time?). Please try to explain that and make your question a bit clearer where possible.

Comment: Will duplicates always have the same id? (As here there are two entries for Audi with id=5 and they are within 40 seconds) - Bad practice to use the same id twice, but if that is what signifies a duplicate that is also easy to solve.

Comment: perfect, my answer should give you what you expect now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Case 1:

```js
function example1(initData, fieldsArr){  
  
  const output = data.reduce((aggObj, item) => {
    const stringId = fieldsArr.map(key => item[key]).join('_');
    
    if (aggObj[stringId]){
      aggObj[stringId].push(item);
    }
    else {
      aggObj[stringId] = [item];
    }

    return aggObj;
  }, {})
  
  const outputNoDups = Object.values(output).map(group => {
  
    const sorted = group.sort((a,b) => new Date(a.transaction) < new Date(b.transaction) ? -1 : 1);
    
    return sorted.filter((a, i) => {
      if (i == 0) return true;

      if (a.amount == sorted[i - 1].amount &&
          new Date(a.transaction) - new Date(sorted[i - 1].transaction) <= 45000){
        return true;
      }
      
      return false;
    });
  });
  
  return outputNoDups.filter(a => a.length > 1);
}  

console.log(example1(data, ['manufacturer', 'category']));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script id="initData">
const data = [{
    id: 3,
    manufacturer: 'audi',
    amount: 40,
    category: 'leasing',
    transaction: '2020-03-02T10:34:30.000Z'
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    manufacturer: 'audi',
    amount: 40,
    category: 'leasing',
    transaction: '2020-03-02T10:34:38.000Z'
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    manufacturer: 'mercedes',
    amount: 20,
    category: 'leasing',
    transaction: '2020-03-05T12:00:00.000Z'
  },
  {
    id: 7,
    manufacturer: 'audi',
    amount: 40,
    category: 'leasing',
    transaction: '2020-03-20T11:00:00.000Z'
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    manufacturer: 'mercedes',
    amount: 20,
    category: 'leasing',
    transaction: '2020-03-05T12:00:44.000Z'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    manufacturer: 'volkswagen',
    amount: 2,
    category: 'credit',
    transaction: '2020-03-05T12:00:45.000Z'
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    manufacturer: 'audi',
    amount: 40,
    category: 'leasing',
    transaction: '2020-03-02T10:35:17.000Z'
  },
];
</script>
```

OUTPUT (Case 1):

```js
[
  [
    {
      "id": 3,
      "manufacturer": "audi",
      "amount": 40,
      "category": "leasing",
      "transaction": "2020-03-02T10:34:30.000Z"
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "manufacturer": "audi",
      "amount": 40,
      "category": "leasing",
      "transaction": "2020-03-02T10:34:38.000Z"
    },
    {
      "id": 5,
      "manufacturer": "audi",
      "amount": 40,
      "category": "leasing",
      "transaction": "2020-03-02T10:35:17.000Z"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "manufacturer": "mercedes",
      "amount": 20,
      "category": "leasing",
      "transaction": "2020-03-05T12:00:00.000Z"
    },
    {
      "id": 6,
      "manufacturer": "mercedes",
      "amount": 20,
      "category": "leasing",
      "transaction": "2020-03-05T12:00:44.000Z"
    }
  ]
]
```

Case 2:

```js
function example1(initData, fieldsArr){  
  
  const output = data.reduce((aggObj, item) => {
    const stringId = fieldsArr.map(key => item[key]).join('_');
    
    if (aggObj[stringId]){
      aggObj[stringId].push(item);
    }
    else {
      aggObj[stringId] = [item];
    }

    return aggObj;
  }, {})
  
  const outputNoDups = Object.values(output).map(group => {
  
    const sorted = group.sort((a,b) => new Date(a.transaction) < new Date(b.transaction) ? -1 : 1);
    
    return sorted.filter((a, i) => {
      if (i == 0) return true;

      if (a.amount == sorted[i - 1].amount &&
          new Date(a.transaction) - new Date(sorted[i - 1].transaction) <= 45000){
        return true;
      }
      
      return false;
    });
  });
  
  return outputNoDups.filter(a => a.length > 1);
}  

console.log(example1(data, ['manufacturer', 'category']));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script id="initData">
const data = [{
    id: 2,
    manufacturer: 'audi',
    amount: 40,
    category: 'leasing',
    transaction: '2020-03-02T10:34:30.000Z'
  },
  {
    id: 7,
    manufacturer: 'audi',
    amount: 40,
    category: 'leasing',
    transaction: '2020-03-20T11:00:00.000Z'
  }]
</script>
```

Case 3:

```js
function example1(initData, fieldsArr){  
  
  const output = data.reduce((aggObj, item) => {
    const stringId = fieldsArr.map(key => item[key]).join('_');
    
    if (aggObj[stringId]){
      aggObj[stringId].push(item);
    }
    else {
      aggObj[stringId] = [item];
    }

    return aggObj;
  }, {})
  
  const outputNoDups = Object.values(output).map(group => {
  
    const sorted = group.sort((a,b) => new Date(a.transaction) < new Date(b.transaction) ? -1 : 1);
    
    return sorted.filter((a, i) => {
      if (i == 0) return true;

      if (a.amount == sorted[i - 1].amount &&
          new Date(a.transaction) - new Date(sorted[i - 1].transaction) <= 45000){
        return true;
      }
      
      return false;
    });
  });
  
  return outputNoDups.filter(a => a.length > 1);
}  

console.log(example1(data, ['manufacturer', 'category']));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script id="initData">
const data = [{
    id: 2,
    manufacturer: 'audi',
    amount: 40,
    category: 'leasing',
    transaction: '2020-03-02T10:34:30.000Z'
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    manufacturer: 'audi',
    amount: 40,
    category: 'credit',
    transaction: '2020-03-02T10:34:40.000Z'
  }]
</script>
```

Case 4 (an edge case you hadn't considered - time is less than 45 but amount is different):

```js
function example1(initData, fieldsArr){  
  
  const output = data.reduce((aggObj, item) => {
    const stringId = fieldsArr.map(key => item[key]).join('_');
    
    if (aggObj[stringId]){
      aggObj[stringId].push(item);
    }
    else {
      aggObj[stringId] = [item];
    }

    return aggObj;
  }, {})
  
  const outputNoDups = Object.values(output).map(group => {
  
    const sorted = group.sort((a,b) => new Date(a.transaction) < new Date(b.transaction) ? -1 : 1);
    
    return sorted.filter((a, i) => {
      if (i == 0) return true;

      if (a.amount == sorted[i - 1].amount &&
          new Date(a.transaction) - new Date(sorted[i - 1].transaction) <= 45000){
        return true;
      }
      
      return false;
    });
  });
  
  return outputNoDups.filter(a => a.length > 1);
}  

console.log(example1(data, ['manufacturer', 'category']));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script id="initData">
const data = [{
    id: 2,
    manufacturer: 'audi',
    amount: 40,
    category: 'leasing',
    transaction: '2020-03-02T10:34:30.000Z'
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    manufacturer: 'audi',
    amount: 30,
    category: 'leasing',
    transaction: '2020-03-02T10:34:40.000Z'
  }]
</script>
```

Comment: I think your output is inconsistent and unclear. Please clarify and I can easily solve it. Why would id=2 (volkswagen, credit) not be included in output for case 1? I don't understand why you want to exclude that. Also, when there is a duplicate (within 40 seconds, which one is kept - the one which was "earlier" in time?). Please try to explain that and make your question a bit clearer where possible.

Comment: When there is only one transaction within specified conditions (in this case Volkswagen does not have similar transaction) it should be excluded from Duplicates array (which by definition should include 2 or more transactions).

Comment: All transactions should be kept if the time difference between the last one and following one is less than 45 seconds.

Comment: Please also check the entire datestamp. Sometimes the days of the month are different so the object should not be included in an array.

Comment: Works fine on case 1, but the same code should also work for case 2 and case 3. Right now it produces same output for all three cases, but in case 2 and 3 should output an empty array.

Comment: Case 2 and 3 produce empty arrays, I had already worked that functionality into the answer (see the final return statement ``return outputNoDups.filter(a => a.length > 1);``). If you had changed the data from case 1 to case 2 or case 3 and run it you would have seen an empty array - see the updated answer, which now also includes those two cases (no code changes, just change the input data).